# Maintain Ownership While Updating Symbolic Links

Tags: ln

I'm migrating a file system and I need to update a few thousand symbolic links that'll break as a result of the migration. My plan was to find all the affected links and build a script that'd process each link. For example:

```
ln -nsf "$(readlink "./somelink1" | sed "s|oldpath|newpath|") "$(echo "./somelink1" | sed "s|oldpath|newpath|")"
ln -nsf "$(readlink "./somelink2" | sed "s|oldpath|newpath|") "$(echo "./somelink2" | sed "s|oldpath|newpath|")"
```

I'll need to run the script as root, however, it looks like that'll change the ownership of the all the links to root:root. Is there a way I can update the links and keep the existing UID:GID? I'm sure I can capture the ownership while the links are enumerated and add a command to chown each link, but I'm wondering if there is a better way to retain ownership?

Comment: AFAIK the only time symbolic link ownership really matters is when it's in a directory with the sticky bit set and that this bit prevents users deleting files they do not own. Not answering your question, mind, but it may help your perspective

Comment: A possible alternative approach, but I don't know if it's actually easier: tar all the links, use [python `tarfile`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tarfile.html) to edit the tar, untar. At least with GNU tar, untarring preserves the ownership and timestamp of symlinks.